# Lua table removing duplicates

Tags: lua

Can anyone offer an alternative to removing duplicates from an numeric indexed
table that will keep a record of the duplicate?, this one works but on tables of
1000 or more entries it just seems to eat the cpu that in turn gives "not responding"
in the app lua is embedded in.

> ```
>    local Dupes ={}  
>    local t2 = {};  
>    for i,v in pairs(t1) do   
>     Count = table.getn(t2)     
>     t2[v] = i  
>     Count1 = table.getn(t2)   
>      if Count == Count1 then  
>       table.insert(Dupes,v)  
>      end  
>    end
> ```

Comment: Are you still using Lua 5.0? Because `getn` isn't in 5.1 or above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really see the purpose of the use of `getn`. Just test to see if it's already there:

```
local Dupes ={}  
local t2 = {};  
for i,v in pairs(t1) do
    if(t2[v] ~= nil) then
        table.insert(Dupes,v)
    end
    t2[v] = i
end
```

Comment: the getn was to check a difference, your way works real quick thanks (yeh its 5 embedded in an app)